# inserting form data into mysql fails when using CURRENT_TIMESTAMP?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to insert the data from my form into mysql, this works fine but when i add a 'date_created' column with TimeStamp and CURRENT_TIMESTAMP it causes the sql query to fail?

Can anyone tell me why this is?

Here's my mysql function:

```
<?php ob_start(); 

// CONNECT TO THE DATABASE
    require('../includes/_config/connection.php');
// LOAD FUNCTIONS
    require('../includes/functions.php');


$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$age = $_POST['age'];
$gender = $_POST['gender'];
$country = $_POST['country'];




$query="INSERT INTO ptb_registrations (ID,
username,
password,
firstname,
lastname,
email,
age,
gender,
country

 )
VALUES('NULL',
'".$username."',
'".$password."',
'".$firstname."',
'".$lastname."',
'".$email."',
'".$age."',
'".$gender."',
'".$country."'
)";
mysql_query($query) or die ('Error updating database');
?>


<?php include ('send_email/reg_email.php'); ?>

<? ob_flush(); ?>
```

Comment: Can you post the error given to you by MySQL?

Comment: `mysql_error()` says what?

Comment: *Obligatory:* The `mysql_*` functions will be [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: what type is your column of date_created?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this to add date/time column to your table. then try again to insert the query and see if it works:

```
   ALTER TABLE table_name ADD timeanddate_colname TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Answer (score 0):

if your column is not timestamp then alter your table like that

```
  ALTER TABLE table_name ADD DEFAULT (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) FOR [Cold2]
```

or there is other cases if you can add curent_date by `CURDATE()` or `NOW()`